# html and javascript - how to update innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update the innerHTML for a div tag and maybe something is wrong in the simple application here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
 <script> 
    var element = document.getElementById("aaa");
    element.innerHTML = "1";
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the "aaa" to be "1" when I see it in a browser.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: The JS is being executed before the DOM has loaded. You [should read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model) about Document Object Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your script is executing, there is no `#aaa` element visible for JavaScript.

The good practice is to put your `<script>` tag right before `</body>`, so the script will be executed when all the document is loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="aaa">aaa</div>

    <script> 
        var element = document.getElementById("aaa");
        element.innerHTML = "1";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because when your script is executed the element `aaa` is not yet added to the dom.

The safer method to do dom manipulation is to do it after the dom is loaded, for that you can use the onload event handler.

Another tip related to html loading is to place all the scripts at the bottom of the page.

You need to move your script to on load

```
<html lang="en" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
 <script> 
    window.onload = function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("aaa");
        element.innerHTML = "1";
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>
 <script> 
    var element = document.getElementById("aaa");
    element.innerHTML = "1";
 </script>
</body>
```

script code should be executed after loading tag with name `'aaa'`
Else use `onload` event function to call the code

Answer (score 0):

On the first look your code is perfectly fine, there's just some tiny problem with it:

Javascript code is executed the moment the parser hits the code block. This results in your code being executed before the actual body of the document is constructed, resulting in `element` being `undefined` rather than pointing to the correct `<div>`.

To solve this issue, wrap your code in a function and then call it in the `onload` event of `<body>`, which will be executed once everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = "1";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
 <head>
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="aaa">aaa</div>
</body>
 <script> 
 var element = document.getElementById("aaa");
 element.innerHTML = "1";
 </script>
 </html>
```

Work only after element loaded